# Execution Stuck by using function of Scipy in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, scipy, azure-functions, signals, spectrogram

I have an Azure Function in which I am using scipy library for sound detection. On signal.spectrogram line, execution stuck. I have checked monitor log of that Azure Function and find attached error. But I did not understand this error.
[image]

How can I find this error and what's the solution of this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See more information about exception go to Function->Code+Test->Test/Run see exception. but its not show full error.

[image]

Go to log Function App -> Application Insights -> Click on failed request.

[image]

Click on Error.
[image]

See full error message
[image]